# Entity Framework - writing query using lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework-4

I have just started Entity Framework & linq and write this query

```
 var query = from rp in db.UM_RolePermission
             where (from ru in db.UM_RoleUser 
             where ru.UM_User.UserID == userId select ru.RoleID).Contains(rp.RoleId)
             select rp;
```

above is working fine and fullfill my need, however I am trying to write this same using lambda expression to understand that as well.

I have tried himself to write this but I was unable to complete it.

```
var query1 = db.UM_RolePermission
             .Where(rp => (from ru in db.UM_RoleUser where ru.UM_User.UserID == userId select ru.RoleID).Contains(rp.RoleId));
```

Can anyone complete this?

RelationShip:

```
UM_RoleUser and UM_User
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = db.UM_RolePermission
            .Where(rp => db.UM_RoleUser
                         .Where(ru => ru.UM_User.UserID == userId)
                         .Select(ru => ru.RoleID)
                         .Contains(rp.RoleId))
```

Answer (score 3):

I going to jump ahead and assume you've defined a relationship between RolePermission and RoleUser in a many-to-many relationship?  That will make your life a lot simpler.

```
var query1 = db.UM_RoleUser
    .Where(ru => ru.UserId == userID)
    .SelectMany(rp => rp.RolePermissions);
```

Of course, this depends on how you've set up your relationships.

Comment: There is no relationship b/w RolePermission & RoleUser

Comment: Why not make one?  It certainly sounds like a natural relationship to me based on what you've told me.